# how to estimate disk size required for subversion

Tags: svn, diskspace

We have a subversion repository for a large application, and create stabilisation branches for each release. Development branches are created as well for major contributions worked on by several people. until now branches are created by the administrator on request. Suppose every developer gets permission to create branches for his contributions (typically to or three at a time) how can I estimate the additional disk space needed for that?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Branches in subversion are very cheap in terms of disk space. And the best way to estimate the disk requirements of any VCS  is to monitor its useage for a period. Different teams will have different work patterns and different kinds of data under version control, so simple rules of thumb don't apply too well.